# What to do with unmarried kinswomen?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have several healthy, young and fertile kinswomen at my court. Unfortunately, no one wants to marry them matrilineally. I tried looking for duchy and county title claimants, the default search list, lowborns all over the world and no one wants to marry them (Your kinswoman is unimportant: -----).
The reason why i want to marry them matrilineally is because i want them to breed more kinsmen so i can further strenghten my dynasty and occasionally get a weak claim or two, but it seems i am only able to send them off into regular marriages, which to me, seems like a waste of good women, since they dont even give me alliances.

Is there a way to lure some sucker from another court into marrying them matrielineally?
Also, incest is not an option, i dont want to risk having inbreds in my glorious dynasty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It wouldn't help with claims, but you could use your gold to invite a nobleman to your court (through the intrigue menu), and then have your kinswomen marry them. This way you get a noble plus the offspring of their marriage, which can help if you are short on potential council members.

It will be difficult to lure men to marry matrilineally, especially if they have any sort of claims. They won't want to marry your unimportant kinswoman, and there is a base reluctance to the marriage anyway. Hover over the "No" message to see what factors are preventing the marriage, and how close you are to success.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked. The only downside is, you'll have to spend quite a lot of gold if you have many kinswomen to marry.

Comment: Use "Invite Holy Man" to use your piety, if you'd rather spend that  instead.

Answer (score 5):

1. Find a title you want.
2. Go to claimants.
3. See if any male claimants want to join your court, maybe bribe him.
4. Matrilineairly marry him to your kinswoman wen he arrives at your court. You might have to kill his wife and any offspring.
5. Now you can press his claim or let your kin inherit the claim.

Comment: _"You might have to kill his wife and any offspring"_ this is beautiful, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you can always matrilineally marry them to courtiers with high stats, in the hopes that they'll produce talented offspring. It's always useful to have talented dynasty members around to give newly conquered lands to, especially if you use elective monarchy since that lets you pretty pick the most talented member of your dynasty as your heir.